# Calling SSIS package from stored procedure under a different account

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, proxy

I have a stored procedure which runs and calls an SSIS pacakge using EXEC SSISDB.CATALOG.start_execution @Execution_Id method.

However I need the package to execute under a service account with more privileges and not the user's account.

using the EXECUTE AS LOGIN = doesn't work.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this.  The only other way I know involves Agent Jobs and proxy accounts.

Surely there is a simply way to accomplish this on SQL 2012 ?

Comment: I have solved this in the past using the Agent Jobs and proxy accounts you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

'EXECUTE AS' works fine for me.

One thing to note is to switch context to the SSIS Catalog database, before calling the execute method. Hence the 'USE ' statement on top.

```
USE SSISDB;
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'domain\user'

DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT
EXEC CATALOG.create_execution @folder_name = 'MyFolder1',
    @project_name = 'MyProject', @package_name = 'Package.dtsx',
    @use32bitruntime = 1, @execution_id = @execution_id OUTPUT;

EXEC CATALOG.start_execution @execution_id;
```